# What's the [pyspark-pandas] tag about?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

There's a [pyspark-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark-pandas) tag that has a lot of irrelevant questions. Almost all the questions are of purely [pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark).

I suspect the misuse is due the fact that the tag has no usage guidance. Given that spark has introduced [Pandas API on Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html#pandas-api-on-spark), it'd be great to update the tag's guidance to use it for the linked API.

Comment: Is your question what pyspark-pandas is or is your question "can someone please add a tag wiki description"?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered on Stack Overflow itself, ironically (though about the technology itself, of course... not the tag): [What is the difference between pyspark.pandas to pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73788459/what-is-the-difference-between-pyspark-pandas-to-pandas) which you have already commented on.

From the current [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73788459/what-is-the-difference-between-pyspark-pandas-to-pandas/73788769#73788769) there:

> PySpark is an interface for Apache Spark in Python. It allows you to write Spark applications using Python and provides the PySpark shell to analyze data in a distributed environment. `Pyspark.pandas` is an API that allows you to use pandas functions and operations on "spark data frames".

And from the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73788459/what-is-the-difference-between-pyspark-pandas-to-pandas/73789018#73789018):

> [pyspark.pandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/frame.html) is an alternative to pandas, with the same api than pandas. This means you can work with pyspark exactly the same as you work with pandas
>
> for example, to create a dataframe, you use .DataFrame same as with pandas, and use .iloc or .drop_duplicates
> [...]

In short, it seems like it lets you write Pandas code (think writing jQuery for JavaScript) directly for/in Spark databases/dataframes. So... that's what the tag is for.

Comment: thank you. apologies for not being direct - i'm looking for guidance on the tag usage. however, looks like you've lightly touched on that as well.